# Can macOS Monterey's video effects (e.g. portrait) be used using an external webcam?

Tags: macos, apple-silicon, webcam

With Apple Silicon and macOS Monterey we can, on an app-by-app basis, activate video effects in apps that use the webcam. E.g. on my MBP M1, I can blur my background when in a Google Meet by clicking Control Center » Video Effects » Portrait under Google Chrome.

**Can I use the Video Effects feature through an external webcam on my M1 Mac?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, *these* features do not need any special hardware and are implemented per app. Therefore any camera that is being detected as such by macOS will be able to use these features.

E.g. I am sometimes using my Sony camera connected to my Mac via cable in zoom. All the features, like blurring a background or the bluescreen functionality are still available and work as expected.

---

Note that the head-tracking/focusing feature introduced in the newer iPads and the new Studio display only work with the "internal" camera.